# C++ vs Python execution time mathematical operations

Tags: python, c++, performance

I have the same code in two different languages: C++ and Python.

C++ code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
float m = 16442.34;
float c = 2434.1; 
float t = 0.34;
int n = 3;
float i = 934380.72;
int k = 111;
int ris = 0;
int tot = 0;

int main() {
    while(tot<1000000){
        ris++;
        tot = (ris * (m - c)) - (int(ris/n) *  t * m * n) - (i * int(ris/k));
    }
    std::cout << ris << " steps\n";
}
```

Python code:

```py
m = 16442.34
c = 2434.1
t = 0.34 
n = 3 
i = 934380.72 
k = 111
ris = 0
tot = 0

while tot<1000000:
    ris+=1
    tot = (ris * (m - c)) - (int(ris/n) *  t * m * n) - (i * int(ris/k))
print(ris, "steps")
```

Why is there a huge difference in execution time? Is it possible to speed up the Python code? How?

Comment: Compile it, or move as much logic as possible into a compiled module.

Comment: What do you mean "compile it"? What's a compiled module? Could you expand on that and post an answer?

Comment: More specifically, C++ can [optimize all the code away](https://godbolt.org/z/PvM7sd7bo) (assuming typos are fixed and no other code).

Comment: @J.P.S. - About ~62x slower to reach C++'s `33744110 steps` in python, that is to be expected. But not with the same result, so it goes on much longer. Doesn't seem like a particularly good benchmark. Naive `@numba.jit` runs 3x slower than C++, but with 24x more steps ('830601566 steps') to end the while loop (I don't know why), twice as fast for `33744110 steps`. And I learnt that you can `!g++` compile in google colab, that is nice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python is an interpreted language while C++ gets compiled to machine code. This enables a C++ compiler to produce highly optimized code while the python interpreter "has to think more in order to execute the program".

You could compile the python code (as Samwise said), e.g., with [Cython](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/tutorial/cython_tutorial.html).

Also, you are using 32-bit floats in C++ which yield different floating point errors than the 64-bit (?) numbers of python. Changing the type from `float` to `double` at least created the same (apart from minor floating point errors) result for `tot` and `ris`. Thanks @Michael Szczesny for pointing towards this bug.

Comment: Looking at the constants, this question seems tailored to include this 'bug'.

Comment: You're right, 32-bit floats usually have something around "6 decimal digits" for the mantissa. These numbers and calculations throw away a lot of information.